# Gentoo Hardened eats 3 GB of memory after running for ~12 hours with very few processes running

Tags: memory, gentoo

I'm running Gentoo Hardened AMD64 using kernel 4.3.3-hardened-r4. With my system only running some basic daemons like wpa_supplicant, cron or DHCP, and with an X session with only Windowmaker, GKrellM and xterm open, Linux starts eating more and more RAM as time goes on until after some 8-12 hours it ends up running out of RAM and throws a kernel panic. This is not a matter of Linux reporting RAM used for buffers and filesystem cache as taken, because top, htop and GKrellM both account for these cases and display how much RAM is actually taken by processes. Up until recently I thought it was linked to my Bitcoin Core client, but that was not the case (I just casually happened to run that app while my Linux system was up).

I was able to see in a few instances my RAM usage suddenly jumping back to normal while issuing a full world update (`emerge -NDu --with-bdeps=y @world`), but I haven't been able to reproduce this workaround.

So far I've tried the following fixes:

1. Compiling NUMA support on my kernel (by default not enabled by Gentoo's genkernel) and adding `vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1` to my sysctl. Didn't work.
2. Adding `vm.drop_caches=1` to my sysctl. Didn't work.
3. Checking whether a tmpfs mount was getting full. My tmpfs mounts hardly even register over 1 MB of filesystem usage.

Evidence of this behavior can be seen in these screenshots:

**Exhibit A:** In which the only memory-eating processes that are running are Firefox, GKrellm and X yet Linux is eating almost 3 GB of core.
**Note:** I didn't have my swap space enabled here (it's on an USB 3.0 external HD because my internal HD is old and slow), but even with swap enabled I still end up with an OOM kernel panic after 8+ hours of keeping Bitcoin Core running.

[image]

**Exhibit B:** Just in case htop and GKrellm are flawed, I double-checked with top. Same result.

[image]

**Exhibit C:** My tmpfs mount usage statistics, my output of `free` and my content of `/proc/meminfo` [available here.](http://pastebin.com/Xzez2Pjh)

This post has been greatly edited to account for my most recent findings. The old post can be found on [this Pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/Fwk5Wp6U).

Comment: This, maybe? http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Not my case. htop and GKrellm both ignore caches and buffers when calculating claimed RAM.

Comment: Try adding vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1 to your sysctl.conf

Comment: I get `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode: No such file or directory`. Given that I use Gentoo, this usually means I haven't compiled this feature. However, I couldn't find anything neither on `make menuconfig` nor on the internet.

Comment: Would also like to clarify that I did this manually instead of adding this parameter to sysctl.conf, I used `sysctl vm.zome_reclaim_mode=1` on a ROOT shell.

Comment: OK, now I have a new development: I just got the same error, but without having Bitcoin Core open. Instead, I had Firefox and KDirstat. The error could indeed be in my kernel.

Comment: And now, I left my computer doing nothing at all and yet my computer will still eat memory. So now I have to figure out how to compile zone reclaim mode, and the internet doesn't seem to know how to do that.

Comment: Now that I figured out that I had to compile my kernel with `CONFIG_NUMA` enabled, I tried keeping my system running with `vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1` on. There is a little bit of difference (it seems like my system can now stay up for more than 8 hours at a time), but Linux still keeps eating RAM out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after almost two months of puzzling over this question, I decided to ask around how to enable that `vm.zone_reclaim_mode` sysctl option and play a little with different values, and lo and behold -- problem solved.

Solution:

1. Enable `CONFIG_NUMA` on my kernel's configuration and rebuild it.
2. Put `vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 7` on sysctl.conf

Now my system can finally stay in one piece for over 24 hours.

I'm a bit afraid of reduced performance since the kernel documentation says both NUMA and such an aggressive zone reclaim setting could probably slow things down, but for now my system finally works.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an SHM based mount, such as memory-backed `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`? It's possible that temporary files are being generated which consume ram even after the process exits. These files will remain in ram until they are deleted or the system is restarted. Check your mounts in `/etc/fstab` and also with `mount` for tmpfs entries.

Also check your log rotation, as it might be creating large files in a temp directory. It might be worth clearing the journal if you're using systemd. e.g:

```
journalctl --vacuum-size=500M
```

Comment: As far as I remember, my tmpfs mounts were pretty much empty. Will confirm later today once I return home.

Comment: As for log rotation, I use OpenRC (default init in Gentoo).

Comment: I switched from OpenRC to systemd 2 years ago for gnome3. I miss it sometimes. Are you using syslog-ng?

Comment: Please post the output from free as well when you get a chance

Comment: Oh and the output of /proc/meminfo would be helpful

Comment: I do use syslog-ng but can't remember if I have it on autostart.

Comment: On my computer now. I do use syslog-ng and I have it on autostart (runlevel default).

Comment: I'm going to let Bitcoin Core run for a few hours to reproduce my memory usage condition.

Comment: Done. Here's my tmpfs mount usage (almost empty), output of `free` and content of `/proc/meminfo`. http://pastebin.com/Xzez2Pjh

Comment: @RAKK I don't see anything unusual here, so I'm not sure what the issue is either!  You can debug some of the memory usage of bitcoin with "valgrind --leak-check=yes bitcoind". Good luck

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up:

- After using BitCoin client, it starts eating up you ram to the point where it crashes
- It doesn't return memory(until you do something strange)

The first one looks like a classic memory leak. You can check the performance and memory management of the program by using `valgrind`, but it will slow it down considerably.

The second one could be the offspring of the first problem. I do not know why is this happening, but I can only guess that because of the problems with the memory(or large memory consumption, or maybe some other bug - e.g. process stuck on D state?). Since other applications don't show the same behavior, I'd guess that the problem is the bitcoin software, and not your system.

Therefore, everything we do to fix it would be a hack. There might be a successful hack, but it's still not the best way. If you have an access to the source code, and know a bit of programming, you can try running some static code analyzer to see if there are any 'simple' bugs to fix. You can try debugging its memory management with `valgrind`. If you don't have any of these(code/skills), last thing you can do is give feedback to the devs - probably some bugtracker, forum or mailing list. This way someone will look into it, and confirm (and hopefully fix) the problem.

Comment: Time to consider an actual bug report? I never thought I'd ever get to that point...

Comment: @RAKK Bugs happen. I've filed many bugs report throughout my life, it only sounds scary. Often it's also a good idea to get in touch with someone who might know the situation better - so even if it's not a bug, you are likely to get an answer. You don't need to spend that much time too - a win-win situation.